# Fetching address from contact but still getting number?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using below code for fetching the number from contact but I am still getting the mobile number of the contact.

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext())
    {

      String address=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS));

      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Address is:"+address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
    }
```

In the toast I am getting the mobile number of a contact but I need the address which is stored by mobile user.

Thanks.

Comment: you need `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal#CONTENT_URI` as an `Uri`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to fetch complete address

```
String addrWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?"; 
    String[] addrWhereParams = new String[]{id, 
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}; 
    Cursor addrCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, 
                null, where, whereParameters, null); 
    while(addrCur.moveToNext()) {
        String poBox = addrCur.getString(
                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
        String street = addrCur.getString(
                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
        String city = addrCur.getString(
                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
        String state = addrCur.getString(
                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
        String postalCode = addrCur.getString(
                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
        String country = addrCur.getString(
                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
        String type = addrCur.getString(
                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE));
    } 
    addrCur.close();
```